# How to make full row update of datagridView one row clicking edit column with inserted controls c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to update of name and date row update using DatagridViewButtonColumn in my DatagridView. But I can't set TextBox and DateTimePicker in specific row where I click Button "EditRow". [image]. It should after clicking "EditRow" add two controls Textbox and DateTimePicker in chosen row insted of two columns.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public Form1()
   {
    InitializeComponent();

    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1, "Date1", "2024-12-13");
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(2, "Date2", "2024-11-12");
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(3, "Date3", "2024-10-22");
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(4, "Date4", "2024-04-04");
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(5, "Date5", "2024-02-22");
    AddControlsToDatagridViewSelectedRow();
}
TextBox txtBx = new TextBox();
DateTimePicker dtpckr = new DateTimePicker();

private void AddControlsToDatagridViewSelectedRow()
{
    dataGridView1.Controls.Add(txtBx);
    dataGridView1.Controls.Add(dtpckr);
    txtBx.Visible = false;
    dtpckr.Visible = false;
}


private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "editColumn")
    {
        DataGridViewButtonColumn dgvbtn = (DataGridViewButtonColumn)sender;
        if (dgvbtn.Text == "Edit")
        {
            dgvbtn.Text = "Save";

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            {
                txtBx.Text  = row.Cells["nameColumn"].Value.ToString();
                dtpckr.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["dateColumn"].Value).Date ;
            }

            txtBx.Visible = true;
            dtpckr.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            dgvbtn.Text = "Edit";

            SaveCahngesToDBFunction();

            txtBx.Visible = false;
            dtpckr.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}

 private void SaveCahngesToDBFunction()
 {
    //Udpate row
 }
  }
```

It should look like this: https://www.vanderwaal.eu/mini-projecten/gridview-edit-and-update-demo

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8